# Resizable Button with background in flash CS4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, components

I want to create a button which resize dynamically with content. to achieve this, I created a MovieClip in library and added four layers into it namely - text, bg, shadow and border.

Problem I'm having is, if I make textfield autosize, only textfield resizes and others stuff remain as it is. if I calculate width required using xxxLineMetrics function and apply it to Button, background resizes properly but textfield also stretches with them and looks ugly.

I want backgrounds(sibling of textfield) resize properly with textfield so button looks nice with resized background and normal autosized textfield.

I hope u guys got what I want...any help appreciated...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you should apply the calculated width to the bg movieclip only and not to the whole movieclip. Because this will change the textfield's width too.

so try something like this:

```
txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
txt.text = "label";
btn.bg.width = txt.width;
```

Comment: and your textfiels isn't a child of your background movieclip?

Comment: My TExtFields and Background Sprite/Image both are siblings - child of a parent Sprite.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the code below:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    /**
     * class represents the MyButton Movieclip in your library containing a dynamic 
     * textfield with instancename txt 
     * and a background movieclip with instance name bg
     */
    public class MyButton extends MovieClip
    {
        public var txt : TextField;
        public var bg : MovieClip;

        public function MyButton(label : String) 
        {
            txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            txt.text = label;
            bg.width = txt.width;
        }

    }
}
```